# What's wrong with this regex /^([^-]*)( - *.)?/?

Tags: regex, perl

Consider this:

```
my @str = ("Farbkeil","L 0AA61 Rec","L 0AA61 Rec - 150 dpi",,"L 0AA61 Rec - 400 dpi");
for my $s (@str) {
#   my ($m) = ($s =~ /^([^-]*)(?=-)/);
#   my ($m) = ($s =~ /^([^-]*) (?=-)/);
    my ($m) = ($s =~ /^([^-]*)( - *.)?/);
    print "$s => -$m-\n";
}
```

It produces this output

```
Farbkeil => -Farbkeil-
L 0AA61 Rec => -L 0AA61 Rec-
L 0AA61 Rec - 150 dpi => -L 0AA61 Rec -
L 0AA61 Rec - 400 dpi => -L 0AA61 Rec -
```

What I want is to get rid of the space before the optional "-", so that it looks like

```
Farbkeil => -Farbkeil-
L 0AA61 Rec => -L 0AA61 Rec-
L 0AA61 Rec - 150 dpi => -L 0AA61 Rec-
L 0AA61 Rec - 400 dpi => -L 0AA61 Rec-
```

I've tried the above regexes, the last one is the closest but not quite. Guessing didn't work either, surprisingly... Of course I could just trim the result, but there must be a more elegant way?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just remove `/ - .*/`

```
for my $s (@str) {
    (my $m = $s) =~ s/ - .*//;
    print "$s => [$m]\n";
}
```

In more recent Perls, you can use `/r`:

```
my $m = $s =~ s/ - .*//r;
```

Comment: Ok, a substitute instead of a match. Why didn't I think of that? Thanks.

Comment: I will accept your answer because it is the shortest solution to the problem and I ended up using it instead of my rather complicated approach (that was a heritage of older versions of the code where I use this...).

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex for match:

```
/^([^-]+)(?=\s-|$)/
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/gN8jK3/2)

`(?=\s-|$)` is a lookahead that makes sure first part `([^-]+)` is always followed by a *space + hyphen* OR *end of input*.

Comment: Nice. Using an alternation didn't occur to me.

Answer (score 2):

And another one. Just because it requires only one small change to your initial Regex. (note the `\b` outside the round brackets). `\b` is for word boundary.

```
my @str = ("Farbkeil","L 0AA61 Rec","L 0AA61 Rec - 150 dpi",,"L 0AA61 Rec - 400 dpi");
for my $s (@str) {
    my ($m) = ($s =~ /^([^-]*)\b(-)?/);
    print "$s => -$m-\n";
}
```

As for *why* your Regex failed:

`([^-]*)` greedily matches everything that is not a `-`. Thus it always matches the trailing space if it's there. The `\b` forces a stop and can match amongst others a space or end of line.

Comment: I like that one... it does exactly what I MEANT but failed to do! In this example it works the same without the ( - )? part.